# Navigation with react-native-material-bottom-navigation package

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I started using react-native-material-bottom-navigation in my application made with react-native to do navigation between screens. The problem I'm having is that I did not understand the usage mode.

I usually use the 'onPress={on.Press}' function to take the user to another screen, but the react-native-material-bottom-navigation package uses another method.

Can any of you guys give me a clear example of how to use react-native-material-bottom-navigation?

At the moment my code looks like this: https://github.com/JVRodrigues256/firebase_reactnative_project